# Regression on large dataset: Why does accuracy drop?

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

I am trying to predict the views on olx's ads. I write a scraper to scrape all the data(50000) ads. When I perform linear regression (on 1400 samples) I got 66% accuracy.But after that I perform on 52000 samples it dropped to 8%. Here is the [Imgcount vs Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX7Dl.png) and [Price vs Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuAg1.png) stats.

Is there any problem with my data? or How can I perform regression on this. I know that this data is very polarized.

I wanted to know what's the problem why my accuracy dropped when I used large dataset.

Thank you for the help.`

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
import seaborn as sns
 url =  '/home/msz/olx/olx/with_images.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col='url')


df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace('.', '')
df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace(',', '')
df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace('Rs', '')
df['price'] = df['price'].astype(int)


df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(',', ' ')
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('\t', '')
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('\n', '')

X = df[['price', 'img']]
y = df['views'] 

print ("X is like ",  X.shape)
print ("Y is like ",  y.shape)

df.plot(y='views', x='img', style='x')  
plt.title('ImgCount vs Views')  
plt.xlabel('ImgCount')  
plt.ylabel('Views')  
plt.show()

df.plot(y='views', x='price', style='x')  
plt.title('Price vs Views')  
plt.xlabel('Price')  
plt.ylabel('Views')  
plt.show()


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.451, random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression  
regressor = LinearRegression() 
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train) 

score = regressor.score(X_test, y_test)

print('Accuracy is : ',score*100)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread your questions and be more specific. Provide code.

Comment: And can I suggest you don't edit back in all the typos that I have just edited out? :0)

Answer (score 0):

Regression is the basic algorithm which works on linear datasets mostly but if you have a large and non liner dataset you have to use another algorithm like k-nearest neighbour or may be decision tree. But I prefer to use Naives Bayes classifier and others.